# How to receive bounced email in iRedmail

Tags: iredmail

I have setup iRedmail from https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-18-04-iredmail-email-server. So far, running well.

I want to know how to setup bounced email sending to sender inbox when an email fails to send ? Currently my users don't have a way to get notified.

Answer (score 0):

[iRedMail](https://www.iredmail.org/) is using [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) as [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent), so you may want to configure bounce related settings there. See the [The Big Picture](https://docs.iredmail.org/used.components.html#the-big-picture) to learn how everything interacts.

See https://www.howtoforge.com/configure-custom-postfix-bounce-messages for a easy-to-follow howto on configuring bounces in Postfix.

For further common questions, please see the extensive [howto](https://docs.iredmail.org/index.html#howto) section of iRedMail.